# Saying "thank you"

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, politeness

I have only ever been taught one Latin translation for "thank you", and it is *gratias agere* (conjugated in a suitable way).
I just checked in [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=gratia&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) that this is indeed an attested use of *gratia*, often with *agere*.

Was this this the only common phrase in classical Latin to express one's gratitude?
Are there other ways to say "thank you" than *gratias tibi ago* and similar variants of *gratias agere*?
If there are several, I would like to know the most common and important ones.
I realize that one possible answer is "no, that's the only phrase"; since proving negatives is hard, I will take your word for it if voting shows that the [expert opinions](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/281/79) coincide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found some alternatives to *gratias tibi ago* in the literature.  I limited my search for simple, conversational thank yous.  These fall into two broad groups:

- Thanks expressed using “thanksgiving”:

***habeo gratiam***

This occurs frequently in Plautus, often standing alone for a straightforward “thank you”.  It also appears in Terence’s *The Brothers*.

> *fateor, habeo gratiam*
>
> I admit it, thank you

Plautus, *Persa*

Here it is with the object of thanks in the dative:

> *Epidico habeas gratiam*
>
> you should thank Epidicus

Plautus, *Epidicus*, act 2, scene 2

***gratum/grata mihi est***

Cicero uses this quite a bit.  A couple of examples:

> *domum meam quod crebro invisis est mihi valde gratum*
>
> thank you very much for keeping a close eye on my house

*Letters to Atticus*, 80 (IV.5), Antium, soon after 79

> *… tamen mihi grata hortatio tua est*
>
> nevertheless, thank you for your encouragement

*De Finibus*, 5.6

Here without the dative pronoun:

> *gratum est quod patriae civem populoque dedisti*
>
> thank you for producing a citizen for the fatherland and the people

Juvenal, *Satires*, 14.70

Here alone:

> *gratum est*
>
> thank you

Seneca, *Medea*, act 3, line 553

Even more brief:

> *quod Lucceio scribis te nostram gloriam commendaturum et aedificium
>   nostrum quod crebro invisis, **gratum***
>
> for writing that you will recommend my glory to Lucceius and for
>   keeping a close eye on my home, **thanks**

Cicero, *Letters to Atticus*, 85 (IV.9), Naples, 27 April 55

- Thanks expressed as pleasure and assent to the preceding
  action/suggestion etc:

***bene facis***

> Iuppiter: *iam nunc irata non es?* / you’re not still angry, are you?
>
> Alcumena: *non sum* / no, I’m not
>
> Iuppiter: *bene facis* / thank you

Plautus, *Amphitryon*, act 3, scene 2

***bene vocas***

Here, combined with *gratia est*:

> Erotium: *eamus intro, ut prandeamus* / let’s go inside and have lunch
>
> Sosia: *bene uocas, tam gratia est* / thanks but no thanks

Plautus, *Menaechmi*, 2.3.36

***bene***

> *“en” inquit, “hospitium”.  “Bene” ego …*
>
> “Welcome” he said.  “Thanks” I replied …

Apuleius, *Metamorphoses*, 1.22

***optime***

> *“nam et a te perfici istam disputationem volo nec tua mihi oratio
>   longa videri potest.” “Optime,” inquam …*
>
> “for I wish that you finish your argument and no speech of yours could
>   seem to me long.”  “Thank you very much” I said …

Cicero, *De Finibus*, 4.44

Comment: Looking at how long my answer is (yikes!), I realise that that last quotation is quite apt really ... :)

Comment: Fantastic answer, and no need to apologize for the length! It's great to have all these collected in one place. _Tuum mihi responsum longum videri non potest. Optime!_

Comment: Bene facis, habeo gratiam!

Answer (score 4):

Primarily when giving thanks to the gods, constructions with [grates](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dgrates) were also used. For example:

*vobis (dis) grates ago atque habeo*.

See more examples by following the link to L&S.

Of course there are many more ways to express thanks. I'm thinking about constructions in the final dative case (*dativus finalis*) such as *tibi honori est* and *tibi laudi est*. But that might be another topic.

Comment: There's also *gratulor* + dative.