# Informal ways of expressing gratitude (and replying to the same) in Latin?

Tags: idiom, vulgar-latin, spoken-language

## Background, modern examples

Most people who learn Latin and who want to gain some oral proficiency, will early on learn the phrase *Grātiās tibī/vōbīs agō*, and simply a *Grātiās!* to match English *Thanks!* But there are many other ways to say thank you in English, depending on circumstances and settings; an obvious one is *Cheers!*, which most people probably associate with British English. To reply to a thank you, we have numerous ways in European languages:

- English: You’re welcome. No worries.
- Deutsch: Bitte. Bitte sehr. Gern geschehen.
- Norsk: Vær så god. Ingenting å takke for. Går så bra. (‘May you be so kind.’ ‘Nothing to thank for.’ ‘[It’s] all well.’)
- Italiano: Prego. Di niente. Non c’è di che.
- Scots: Nae but a little. (Similar to the Italian above.)
- French: De rien. Je t’en prie.

### Ancient examples

In Cassell, I have found amongst others:

- Accepting

  - Benignē dīcis! – You speak kindly! (Thank you.)
  - Alicui aliquid debēre [something good]. [An actual example would be good here.]
- Refusing

  - Benignē dīcis! – You speak kindly! (No, thank you.)
  - Benignē ac līberāliter! – Kindly and nobly! (Or perhaps rather: Kindly, yet nobly!)
  - Rēctē! – Rightly [so]!
- Acknowledging

  - Bene vocās! – I [say it is?] well!
  - [Jam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lfB9mX5UUNU) grātia est! – Now is [the time for] thankfulness → This certainly makes me thankful! (?)¹

## Main question

The above examples highlight what I identify as a problem: They seem to be quite formal, nothing like the *Nae but a liʔle²* of Scots, the *No worries* of English, the *Går så bra* of Norwegian. What I am looking for, then, is **informal, attested ways to express gratitude in Latin** and suitable replies to these. I am looking for *attested forms* from any period and genre (including comedy, scribbling on toilet walls, whore houses – the key word is informal, colloquial, non-elite) by native Latin speakers.

I would prefer that answers are macronised (even for later periods of Latin[*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3bmLi1bKI0&t=180s) [†](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3bmLi1bKI0&t=378s) [‡](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVGGqzJ-g6g) [§](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4344896)) to encourage correct pronunciation. Notes on source and time would be most welcome.

## Of relevance

- [Translation of ‘I am, therefore I thank’](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8882/translation-of-i-am-therefore-i-thank)

## Notes

1. I believe *jam* can be used emphatically, but could not find any sources for it at the moment. Also: *tempus est jocundum!*
2. The way I have heard it uttered, the glottal stop comes in *little*, but it could just as well be at the end of *but* (or perhaps also both).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some examples:

From the *Assinaria*:

```
Democles: Bene hercle facitis ...
          (Well, thanks by god!)
```

From the *Aulularia*:

```
Megadorus: Habeo gratiam.
           (Thanks)
```

From the *Captivi*:

```
Philocrates: Edepol, Hergio. Facis benigne.
             (By Pollux, Hergio, You do me kindly.)
```

and

```
Stalagmus: Quoi peculi nihil est, recte feceris.
           (Seeing as how I have nothing of value, you certainly do me right.)
```

From the *Persa*:

```
Dordalus: Gratiam habeo.
          (Thank you.)
```